# Zip file before uploading in Dropzone

Tags: javascript, zip, dropzone.js

Is there a way to generate zip from file dropped in dropzone and then send that zip file to server?

I'm generating zip from the file using `JSZip` in `sending` event of dropzone:

```
this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
  var zip = new JSZip();
  zip.file("Hello.csv", file);
  zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function(content) {
    // see FileSaver.js
    saveAs(content, "example.zip");
  });
});
```

How do I make dropzone to send this file instead of the one user added?

Comment: According to the author:

This is now possible by using the [`transformFile` option](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-transformFile). – [enyo](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/1327#issuecomment-311940109)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on dropzone 5.7.0, but I used the `"addedFile"` event instead:

```
this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
  if (file.done) {
    return;
  }
  const dz = this;
  dz.removeFile(file);
  let z = new JSZip();
  z.file(file.name, file);
  z.generateAsync({ 
    type: "blob",
    compression: "DEFLATE",
    compressionOptions: { level: 9}
    }).then(function(content) {    
      let f = new File([content], file.name);
      f.done = true;
      dz.addFile(f);
  });
});
```

I added compression (the default for JSZip is `STORE`) and retained the `file.name` to make the zipping transparent to the user (however they will still see the smaller size).

p.s. I'm not loving the addition of the `f.done` field either...better solutions are welcome.

Comment: Really liked this answer. This is zipping every file individually, right?

Comment: @arturojain Thanks, yeah i just tried it with multiple files and seems to work just fine.

Comment: I'm trying to think another way to compress all files in a single zip... maybe using "sendingmultiple" event.